# Storing list into dictionary from excel

Tags: python, excel, list, dictionary, jinja2

I have stored data into list from excel but now I want to store it into dictionary.
[here is the excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n3oEu.png)

[image]

in list it giving output like this.

```
[['Nodeb_IN_New', 107, 'class-default', 'mobility-platinum', 'h1', 7, 'dscp-fc-map', ['ef']], ['', 107, '', 'mobility-gold-new', 'h2', 5, 'dscp-fc-map', ['af41']], ['', 107, '', 'mobility-silver-new', 'l1', 4, 'dscp-fc-map', ['af11', 'af21', 'af31']], ['Nokia_SRAN_S1-MME_X2_IN', 102, '', 'Nokia_SRAN_mobility_platinum', 'h1', 7, 'dscp-fc-map', ['ef', 'nc1']]]
```

same I want into dictionary. I have written this code

```
def myfun(list):
    list = list
    res=dict()
    qos=None

    for row in list:
        if row[0]=="":
            res[qos]['b']=row[1]
            res[qos]['c']=row[2]
            res[qos]['d']=row[3]
            res[qos]['e']=row[4]
            res[qos]['f']=row[5]
            res[qos]['g']=row[6]
            res[qos]['h']=row[7]

        else:
            qos=row[0]
            res[qos]=dict()
            res[qos]['b']=row[1]
            res[qos]['c']=row[2]
            res[qos]['d']=row[3]
            res[qos]['e']=row[4]
            res[qos]['f']=row[5]
            res[qos]['g']=row[6]
            res[qos]['h']=row[7]
```

but it is giving output like this.

```
{'Nodeb_IN_New': {
   'b': 107, 'c': '', 'd': 'mobility-silver-new',
   'e': 'l1', 'f': 4, 'g': 'dscp-fc-map',
   'h': ['af11', 'af21', 'af31']
    }, 
 'Nokia_SRAN_S1-MME_X2_IN': {
   'b': 102, 'c': '', 'd': 'Nokia_SRAN_mobility_platinum', 'e': 'h1', 'f': 7, 'g': 'dscp-fc-map', 'h': ['ef', 'nc1']}}
```

under 'Nodeb_IN_New' I want all the 3 lines(from excel).

Comment: Depending on what you want to achive, it might be worth looking at a library like [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/index.html) that can conveniently read and manipulate tabular data.

Comment: I wanted to store when 'a' column in excel having some value than store everything till next data come into 'a' column.

Comment: @srish take a look at the result of my code that i already put it and let me  know if that's what are you looking for

Answer (score 1):

try this code :

```
import json
l=[['Nodeb_IN_New', 107, 'class-default', 'mobility-platinum', 'h1', 7, 'dscp-fc-map', ['ef']], ['', 107, '', 'mobility-gold-new', 'h2', 5, 'dscp-fc-map', ['af41']], ['', 107, '', 'mobility-silver-new', 'l1', 4, 'dscp-fc-map', ['af11', 'af21', 'af31']], ['Nokia_SRAN_S1-MME_X2_IN', 102, '', 'Nokia_SRAN_mobility_platinum', 'h1', 7, 'dscp-fc-map', ['ef', 'nc1']]]

def myfun(list):
    res=dict()
    qos=None
    d={}
    li=[]
    for row in list:
        if row[0]=="":
            res[qos]=dict()
            res[qos]['b']=row[1]
            res[qos]['c']=row[2]
            res[qos]['d']=row[3]
            res[qos]['e']=row[4]
            res[qos]['f']=row[5]
            res[qos]['g']=row[6]
            res[qos]['h']=row[7]
        else:
            qos=row[0]
            res[qos]=dict()
            res[qos]['b']=row[1]
            res[qos]['c']=row[2]
            res[qos]['d']=row[3]
            res[qos]['e']=row[4]
            res[qos]['f']=row[5]
            res[qos]['g']=row[6]
            res[qos]['h']=row[7]
        x = res.keys()
        keylist = []
        keylist.extend(iter(x))
        if keylist[0] in d.keys():
               d[keylist[0]].append(res[qos])
        else:
               d[keylist[0]] = []
               d[keylist[0]].append(res[qos])
    print(d)
    print(json.dumps(d))
myfun(l)
```

output:

```
{'Nokia_SRAN_S1-MME_X2_IN': [{'d': 'Nokia_SRAN_mobility_platinum', 'f': 7, 'e': 'h1', 'b': 102, 'c': '', 'h': ['ef', 'nc1'], 'g': 'dscp-fc-map'}], 'Nodeb_IN_New': [{'d': 'mobility-platinum', 'f': 7, 'e': 'h1', 'b': 107, 'c': 'class-default', 'h': ['ef'], 'g': 'dscp-fc-map'}, {'d': 'mobility-gold-new', 'f': 5, 'e': 'h2', 'b': 107, 'c': '', 'h': ['af41'], 'g': 'dscp-fc-map'}, {'d': 'mobility-silver-new', 'f': 4, 'e': 'l1', 'b': 107, 'c': '', 'h': ['af11', 'af21', 'af31'], 'g': 'dscp-fc-map'}]}
```

result in json to be readable :

```
    {
  "Nokia_SRAN_S1-MME_X2_IN": [
    {
      "d": "Nokia_SRAN_mobility_platinum",
      "f": 7,
      "e": "h1",
      "b": 102,
      "c": "",
      "h": [
        "ef",
        "nc1"
      ],
      "g": "dscp-fc-map"
    }
  ],
  "Nodeb_IN_New": [
    {
      "d": "mobility-platinum",
      "f": 7,
      "e": "h1",
      "b": 107,
      "c": "class-default",
      "h": [
        "ef"
      ],
      "g": "dscp-fc-map"
    },
    {
      "d": "mobility-gold-new",
      "f": 5,
      "e": "h2",
      "b": 107,
      "c": "",
      "h": [
        "af41"
      ],
      "g": "dscp-fc-map"
    },
    {
      "d": "mobility-silver-new",
      "f": 4,
      "e": "l1",
      "b": 107,
      "c": "",
      "h": [
        "af11",
        "af21",
        "af31"
      ],
      "g": "dscp-fc-map"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: thank u soo much, but it is taking "mobility-silver-new" three times. and I want one for "mobility-platinum',"mobility-gold-new","mobility-silver new". same as it is taking for "mobility-silver-new" I want for that two also.

Comment: {
      "b": 107,
      "c": "class-default",
      "d": "mobility-platinum",
      "e": "h1",
      "f": 7,
      "g": "dscp-fc-map",
      "h": [
        "ef"
      ]
    },
    {
      "b": 107,
      "c": "",
      "d": "mobility-gold-new",
      "e": "h2",
      "f": 5,
      "g": "dscp-fc-map",
      "h": [
        "af41"
      ]
    },
    {
      "b": 107,
      "c": "",
      "d": "mobility-silver-new",
      "e": "l1",
      "f": 4,
      "g": "dscp-fc-map",
      "h": [
        "af11",
        "af21",
        "af31"
      ]
    }
  ]
}

Comment: @srish i already update the code now check it and sorry for the delay

Comment: File "my.py", line 96, in myfun
    print(json.dumps(d))
  File "C:\python3\lib\json\__init__.py", line 231, in dumps
    return _default_encoder.encode(obj)
  File "C:\python3\lib\json\encoder.py", line 199, in encode
    chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
  File "C:\python3\lib\json\encoder.py", line 257, in iterencode
    return _iterencode(o, 0)
  File "C:\python3\lib\json\encoder.py", line 179, in default
    raise TypeError(f'Object of type {o.__class__.__name__} '
TypeError: Object of type int64 is not JSON serializable

Comment: you mentioned this output :  {'Nokia_SRAN_S1-MME_X2_IN': [{'d': 'Nokia_SRAN_mobility_platinum', 'f': 7, 'e': 'h1', 'b': 102, 'c': '', 'h': ['ef', 'nc1'], 'g': 'dscp-fc-map'}], 'Nodeb_IN_New': [{'d': 'mobility-platinum', 'f': 7, 'e': 'h1', 'b': 107, 'c': 'class-default', 'h': ['ef'], 'g': 'dscp-fc-map'}, {'d': 'mobility-gold-new', 'f': 5, 'e': 'h2', 'b': 107, 'c': '', 'h': ['af41'], 'g': 'dscp-fc-map'}, {'d': 'mobility-silver-new', 'f': 4, 'e': 'l1', 'b': 107, 'c': '', 'h': ['af11', 'af21', 'af31'], 'g': 'dscp-fc-map'}]}    but while running the code I am getting this output :

Comment: {'Nodeb_IN_New': [{'b': 107, 'c': 'class-default', 'd': 'mobility-platinum', 'e': 'h1', 'f': 7, 'g': 'dscp-fc-map', 'h': ['ef']}, {'b': 107, 'c': '', 'd': 'mobility-gold-new', 'e': 'h2', 'f': 5, 'g': 'dscp-fc-map', 'h': ['af41']}, {'b': 107, 'c': '', 'd': 'mobility-silver-new', 'e': 'l1', 'f': 4, 'g': 'dscp-fc-map', 'h': ['af11', 'af21', 'af31']}, {'b': 102, 'c': '', 'd': 'Nokia_SRAN_mobility_platinum', 'e': 'h1', 'f': 7, 'g': 'dscp-fc-map', 'h': ['ef', 'nc1']}]} like this, means 'Nokia_SRAN_S1-MME_X2_IN key is missing. please help.

Comment: Try to remove print(json.dumps(d)) to avoid the json error its just an output json that i want to got it  for e second error i will try to make an executable verqion on line because it works well with me

Answer (score 1):

The reason your code isn't working, is that when you are going through the rows and inserting them into the target dictionary `res`, you are also setting the `value` to a sub-dictionary, and in this sub-dictionary, the rows will always go under the same key ‘b’, ‘c’, ‘d’, etc., in other words, the rows at the bottom are overwriting the rows at top, leaving you just the 3rd row for `Nodeb_IN_New`.

---

Another way would be to set the `value` to a list, and go through the rows, append them to this list if they belong to the same `qos`, here's the code:

```
# Original excel sheet in a list
raw_list = [
    ['Nodeb_IN_New', 107, 'class-default', 'mobility-platinum', 'h1', 7, 'dscp-fc-map', ['ef']],
    ['', 107, '', 'mobility-gold-new', 'h2', 5, 'dscp-fc-map', ['af41']],
    ['', 107, '', 'mobility-silver-new', 'l1', 4, 'dscp-fc-map', ['af11', 'af21', 'af31']],
    ['Nokia_SRAN_S1-MME_X2_IN', 102, '', 'Nokia_SRAN_mobility_platinum', 'h1', 7, 'dscp-fc-map', ['ef', 'nc1']]
]

result_dict = {}
# title, will be used as key in the result_dict
title = ""

# Loop through the input list
for row in raw_list:
    # If the first value is not empty, replace the title with this new value
    if row[0] != "":
        # update title
        title = row[0]
        # Insert into the dictionary, and give an empty list as a place holder,
        #  later we can append to this list
        result_dict[title] = []
    # At this stage we can append the rest of the input row to the dictionary value
    result_dict[title].append(row[1:])

print("Result dict: ")
for (key, value) in result_dict.items():
    print("Key: {}".format(key))
    for row in value:
        print("    {}".format(row))
```

And here's the output of the code above:

```
Key: Nodeb_IN_New
    [107, 'class-default', 'mobility-platinum', 'h1', 7, 'dscp-fc-map', ['ef']]
    [107, '', 'mobility-gold-new', 'h2', 5, 'dscp-fc-map', ['af41']]
    [107, '', 'mobility-silver-new', 'l1', 4, 'dscp-fc-map', ['af11', 'af21', 'af31']]
Key: Nokia_SRAN_S1-MME_X2_IN
    [102, '', 'Nokia_SRAN_mobility_platinum', 'h1', 7, 'dscp-fc-map', ['ef', 'nc1']]
```